# Pycharm *.pyd files autocomplete

Tags: python, cython, kivy

I'm using Kivy to build some apps on android. Since kivy makes use of Cython, how can I get for example:

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
```

Note that properties is a Cython compiled file: properties.pyd

How can I make pycharm provide/recognize this file for autocomplete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049842/autocomplete-in-pycharm-for-python-compiled-extensions

Comment: I see, can you provide me more explanation of how to check if the cython instalation is being seen by the interpreter ?

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_interpreter.html :o) Or configuring your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Adding the information of you platform (Win / Linux/ MacOSX) could help but I'm no expert on kivy and Pyton C extensions so I don't know if I'll be able to help you a lot further.

Comment: I see, Iam using windows 8.1 with Pycharm lastest version. I got everything working, the autocomplete is just missing and unresolved reference. Maybe this has something to do with the Cython environment variables... I dont know either. Edit: The unresolved and missing autocomplete is related to Cython compile filed ".pyd"