# Autocomplete in Boost Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I wrote a python wrapper for c++ library that I'm working on using [this repository](https://github.com/Algomorph/pyboostcvconverter). It is using boost python to create wrappers. After the code was compiled, the shared library (.so file) is created. Then I was able to use a python script to execute the c++ functions in that shared library.

But when I'm using the created shared library, my python IDE is not suggesting functions and variables like it does for other python modules. What will I have to do to enable suggestions for the wrappers that I create that way..?

The IDE that I'm using is [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) by JetBrains.

Thanks !!

Comment: Good first step would be sharing with us what concrete IDE you're actually using. ;)

Comment: Does PyCharm highlight or grey-underline or otherwise mark up the `import` statement for the compiled module that it failed to autocomplete?  If so, it is an indication that it can't find that module at edit time.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049842/autocomplete-in-pycharm-for-python-compiled-extensions